# How hide button in Odoo 11?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have a problem a bit weird, I want to hide the button "create invoice" compared to the tasks so I tried the code in addons "sale_timesheet":

**For that (it doesn't work) when adding `tasks_count`:**

```
<button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
                    type="action" context="{'default_advance_payment_method': 'percentage'}"
                    attrs="{'invisible': ['|','|',('tasks_count', '>', 0),('invoice_status', '!=', 'no'), ('state', '!=', 'sale')]}"/>
```

**And for that (it does work) when adding `invoice_count`:**

```
<button name="%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
                        type="action" context="{'default_advance_payment_method': 'percentage'}"
                        attrs="{'invisible': ['|','|',('invoice_count', '>', 0),('invoice_status', '!=', 'no'), ('state', '!=', 'sale')]}"/>
```

And to tell you that fields `tasks_count` and `invoice_count` are in the same model, the same view

What is the problem ! why the error shows me that :

> Field 'tasks_count' used in attributes must be present in view but is missing

Answer (score 2):

You have to put tasks_count field in XML view where you have to create a button. And must put this field before the button. Like the following:

```
    <field name="tasks_count"/>
```

And if you don't want to display this field value then you can keep it invisible like following:

```
    <field name="tasks_count" invisible="1"/>
```

I hope this helps you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

indeed, you can only use the fields that are present in the view. The fields are loaded from the database only if the view asks for it to be loaded ;)